# How to detect each video tag and whether it's playing or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using yall.js to lazy load videos. It works as it should. However I want to add in a loading animation that will sit above the video until it starts playing, so that on slow connection you'll get the first frame and a little loading animation.

I can get the function to work for a singular video, but I want it to work for all videos automatically and individually as other pages will have more videos and I want to have a universal usable code for each page.

I'm using `.each` to detect all the videos which it seems to, but then I want to refer to each iteration to run code against those individual elements, but It's not working for me.

```html
  <video class="full lazy" controls loop muted playsinline>
    <source data-src="video_one.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="a video">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <div class="loader lazy_anim"></div>
</div>
```

```js
$('video').each(function(indVideo) {
  console.log(indVideo);
  var lazyLoader = $('video').next();
  var playCheck = setInterval(function() {
    var videoElement = $('video').get(0); //I want this to refer to the each individual video, but I believe it's just picking the first
    console.log(videoElement.paused);

    if (videoElement.paused) {
      console.log("paused!");
    } else {
      lazyLoader.removeClass('lazy_anim')
      console.log("playing!");
      clearInterval(playCheck);
    };
  }, 2000);
});
```

So the crux of the issue is that the first video is dictating the results and it's not for `.each` iteration individually. I want the `lazy_anim` class to be removed video by video as they begin to play.

I'm super inexperienced with javascript and jquery and I'm just trying to muddle my way through and learn as I go, so please forgive any ignorance on my part. I've been racking my head with this and I haven't been able to figure it out, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried that, and it didn't return an error, but the console is returning videoElement.paused as "undefined", which means the code won't be able to detect if the video is playing or not properly. Usually it returns false/positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have made this more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of having an interval which checks the state of the video elements every 2 seconds, it would make more sense to hook to the `play` and `pause` events on the videos and amend the `lazy_anim` class based on that. Try this:

```js
$('video').on({
  play: function() {
    $(this).next().removeClass('lazy_anim');
  },
  pause: function() {
    $(this).next().addClass('lazy_anim');
  }
});
```

```css
video {
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}

.lazy_anim {
  background-color: #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video class="full lazy" controls loop muted playsinline autoplay>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="a video">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div class="loader lazy_anim">Lazy anim...</div>

<video class="full lazy" controls loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="a video">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div class="loader lazy_anim">Lazy anim...</div>

<video class="full lazy" controls loop muted playsinline>
  <source src="http://grochtdreis.de/fuer-jsfiddle/video/sintel_trailer-480.mp4" type="video/mp4" alt="a video">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<div class="loader lazy_anim">Lazy anim...</div>
```

Comment: Oh my god, I think that happens when you have limited knowledge, I'll have to look into your code to understand it, but it absolutely seems to work exactly as I wish. I don't even need the pause function as it's for autoplaying videos. Really appreciate the help, was trying to get it to work all day yesterday and today.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help. It happens to us all when you get too close to a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on the right track.  When you are inside the function in `.each`, you already have the right element there. Don't do lookup again and don't use `.get(0)`.  You would have something like this:

```
$('video').each(function (indVideo, videoElement) {
    console.log(indVideo);
    var lazyLoader = videoElement.next();
    var playCheck = setInterval(function() {
        console.log(videoElement.paused);
        if (videoElement.paused) {
            console.log("paused!");
        } else {
            lazyLoader.removeClass('lazy_anim')
            console.log("playing!");
            clearInterval(playCheck);
        };
    }, 2000);
});
```

Have a look at the [`.each` function API](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: @dillonbrannick Sorry, my bad, it's the second parameter in the `each` function - I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that there, but It didn't seem to be detecting whether or not is was playing. Rory McCrossan's answer really simplified the situation and it their code seems to work perfectly. Really appreciate your help all the same! Thanks!